# ~site / ~siteCollection token replacement with sandboxed solutions

Tags: 2010, web-part, sandbox-solution

It seems you cannot use the ~site or ~siteCollection tokens in an Element.xml when you deploy as a Sandboxed Solution. Has anyone ever seen this behaviour?

Code snippet:

```
&gt;&lt;sharepoint:SoapDataSource runat="server" SelectUrl="~site/blog/_vti_bin/lists.asmx" InsertUrl=""
```

The ~site token gets replaced by an empty string (i.e. disappears) instead of the site URL upon deployment. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ~Site and ~SiteCollection tokens are part of the Publishing dll which is not allowed in the Sandbox. So they cannot be referenced from your code or aspx pages. However, the tokens can be used with the Elements.xml. I have used them  in the following way:

`<CustomAction Location="ScriptLink" ScriptSrc="~Site/SiteAssets/myScript.js"/>`

Comment: I have the idea that the replacement only works in node attributes. In my case, I need the replacement inside the content of the AllUsersWebPart (inside a CDATA block), there it doesn't seem to be working.